ListView Display Model instead of property
I am currently experiencing a problem with ListView.
When I display the list view, i saw the model not the property (cf: image)

This is my XAML :
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LinkedProject.LinkedAutomateListVM.Automates}" Margin="8">                      
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}" TargetType={x:TypeListViewItem}">
              <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Designation}" Header="Designation" />
           <GridViewColumn
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IpAddress}" Header="IP Address" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

This appends since i have had the BasedOn Property.
When i remove the BasedOn Property, that work's well but i didn't have the material design style.

You must specify a DataTemplate for the ListView.ItemTemplate property or set the ListView.DisplayMemberName property. Otherwise the ListView will simply call ToString on the data item to display it. t simply can't know how to display anything other than a string. You must tell it how to render your data item.

Ok thanks i got it.
I have fix the problem using a Datagrid instead of ListView

You do not set an ItemTemplate when you set the View property. The problem here seems to be the missing ControlTemplate in the ItemContainerStyle.
